# Excel Macro over-writes the value of the variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables, macros

I am writing a Macro that can save the value of a variable (profit) in an Excel table, for multiple scenarios (by changing the price, and discount). To get started I have a macro that runs through each scenario and sets the value of a variable to the profit calculated in that scenario. However, when I run the Macro - all of my three variable A1 A2 and A3 seem to have the last and final value.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
With Sheets("Inputs")
    .Range("I72").Value = "Base"

   Dim A1
    .Range("I5").Value = "Low"
    .Range("I91").Value = "Reduced 8%"
    Set A1 = Range("I174")

    Dim A2
    .Range("I5").Value = "Low"
    .Range("I91").Value = "Reduced 4%"
    Set A2 = Range("I174")

    Dim A3
    .Range("I5").Value = "Low"
    .Range("I91").Value = "Current"
    Set A3 = Range("I174")

    MsgBox A1
    MsgBox A2
    MsgBox A3

End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must declare A1, A2 and A3 as of `Double` type and store there the cell *values*:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '

    '
    With Sheets("Inputs")
        .Range("I72").Value = "Base"

       Dim A1 As Double
        .Range("I5").Value = "Low"
        .Range("I91").Value = "Reduced 8%"
        A1 = Range("I174").Value

        Dim A2 As Double
        .Range("I5").Value = "Low"
        .Range("I91").Value = "Reduced 4%"
        A2 = Range("I174").Value

        Dim A3 As Double
        .Range("I5").Value = "Low"
        .Range("I91").Value = "Current"
        A3 = Range("I174").Value

        MsgBox A1
        MsgBox A2
        MsgBox A3

    End With

End Sub
```

while your code declared them as of `Variant` type (thus making them able to store *every* type) and then you store there a `Range` object using use `Set` keyword, and that range always pointed to the same cell that changed at every calculation

Comment: Thanks a ton, but on runningn your code I keep getting Compile Error: Object required

Comment: Sorry - my bad. There was a typo in my code! Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are over writing the range. Change the cells for A1, A2 and A3 to some other cell values. All 3 are referring to same    cells

Comment: Thanks Mukul, but I am calculating the Profit for each combination of the variable - Price and Discount. The spreadsheet calculates the value of profit and puts it in cell I174. What I want is to capture each unique value of the profit for each different scenario, and hence I am trying to store these unique values of I174 in variables. I would expect that once a variable value is assigned (e.g. A1) it doesnt change, when the source value changes(e.g. I174) in the second or third scenario, however it keeps printing the final value of I174 for all three variables A1, A2 and A3.

Comment: Is it possible to define A1 as a constant and assign the value to it at the end of the scenario? If so, what should the code look like for it?

Comment: Constants once declared cannot be assigned any value. Also, I don't see any code which calculates profit. Your sample code just set text to range. and assigns cell I174, to range A1, A2 and A3.